# join files with numbered index

Tags: text-processing, join

I am trying this command:

```
join -a1 -11 file1 file2 > file3
```

file1 looks like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

file2:

```
1    lkj    klj    lkj
2    lkj    lkj    lkj
3
7    lkj    lkj    lkj
8
9
11    lkk    kll    lkk
```

The output skips the row numbered 11.

While Googling I saw that `join` only understands alphabetical sorting but there must be a way to do this. My aim is to join five 60,000,000 line files for a genetic project.

How can I do this? Are there other tools or options to `join` to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your large files are already sorted. The following method requires no further sorting.

You can simply add leading zeros to the keys, using `sed` ... Because the process is  pipelined, there are no temporary files to deal with. The `sed` overhead it trivial.

---

```
# make key 9 digits    # Add 9 leading 0's       # Remove excess 0's  
join -a1 -11 <(sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)/000000000\1/; s/^0+([0-9]{9})/\1/' file1) \
             <(sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)/000000000\1/; s/^0+([0-9]{9})/\1/' file2)
```

Output is:

```
000000001 lkj klj lkj
000000002 lkj lkj lkj
000000003
000000004
000000005
000000006
000000007 lkj lkj lkj
000000008
000000009
000000010
000000011 lkk kll lkk
```

---

If you don't want the leading zeros in the output, use this command instead.
The extra `sed -r 's/^0+//'` removes leading zeros.

```
join -a1 -11 <(sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)/000000000\1/;s/^0+([0-9]{9})/\1/' file1) \
             <(sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)/000000000\1/;s/^0+([0-9]{9})/\1/' file2) |
               sed -r 's/^0+//'
```

Output

```
1 lkj klj lkj
2 lkj lkj lkj
3
4
5
6
7 lkj lkj lkj
8
9
10
11 lkk kll lkk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the input files, the sort numerically the output:

```
join -a1 -11 <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2) | sort -k1,1n
```